# Django Rest Framework Throttle doesn't work instantly on production

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, throttling

I have an issue with throttling user requests to a certain endpoint. I set the limit for them to make only one request/hour and it works okay locally. However on production, the request may take a bit to return a response and in that case, if the users make any new requests during the processing time, it will pass, until the first request returns a response. Any help or pointers?

Comment: in your throttling do you first check for rate limit and the allow/deny and if allowed then update rate_limit_count? if so, you might need to first change the rate_limit_count and then check for rate_limit and then allow/deny.

Comment: I think its related to django cache.. I tried nginix rate limits but it also continued on doing that behavior.. but I don't check rate_limit.. can you please advise me on how to do that?